# How can I automatically disconnect idle users from a MS Access DB?

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

Here's the problem...

I have a MS Access DB on a shared file server which many users from many sites can access to make a few small edits on a weekly basis.  Occasionally a user with an active connection will abruptly shut down their client server (their laptop) leaving a dangling connection to the DB which results in a DB in limbo which cannot be opened.  Messages indicate that it's corrupted and the option to repair it just hangs.  Not a big deal because I have a task scheduler job that backs-up (copies) the DB every 3 hours and I can just use the most recent backup to restore.  But I can't even delete/clobber the DB with the backup because the dangling process is connected and Windows refuses to let me delete it (which is a problem in and of itself IMO).

The solution is to find the connection, kill it, delete the .accdb and the .laccdb, then replace it with the backup.  But unfortunately, I don't have privs to find/kill the connection, so I have to engage someone in IT to go do that (can take a long time & the person I get often doesn't know how to do this).

What would really alleviate the problem is an automated DB disconnect for client processes that are idle for more than x minutes.  I saw something similar to this using a form.  But my users edit the cells in the tables directly (they like the ExCel style editing over forms).  I searched DB options and don't see an option to set up a idle timeout/disconnect for the DB in general.

Question:  Is there a way to set up an idle timeout like this which will close the DB connection after x minutes?

Question:  Given the problem stated, is there another way to prevent these DB "corruptions".  Everything I've read about this is along the lines of "educate your users to close Access when done".  There are too many users and I doubt they'll pay attention.

Question:  Access seems like a not-so robust DB for this, but the users really want the ExCel style interface (edit cells in records without forms). The record level locking mech seems to work well.  And I love the fact that I can easily set up triggers and constraints to maintain data quality, query the thing with SQL, etc... (ExCel not so good for this).  But if there's a better alternative than Access, I'm all ears.

Thanks for any ideas !

Comment: http://www.accessmvp.com/JConrad/accessjunkie/kickoff.html any reason this wont work? This was the second google result that came back for "ms access idle timeout"

Comment: @ChanceFinley Have you even checked that code yourself? The thing you link to requires the client to be alive, and have you actively check a box to kick them out. That's not at all what OP is looking for. Also, most links on that page are dead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common problem, with no easy solutions.

There are two main approaches for this problem:

1. Use a hidden form with a timer that opens on startup. Have the form check every now and then if a form/datasheet is open, and if the active record or active control on that form/datasheet changes. If it doesn't for a period of time, close down Access.

   The code required for this method is described [here on MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/detect-user-idle-time-or-inactivity), it only requires a few additions for datasheets (tables/queries).

   This method has the limitation that you're shutting down Access for users that are multitasking. If they don't touch Access a while, it's gone, and that's not great UX.

   Another limitation here is that there's a chance a user is kicked out unnecessarily, for example because he's moving data from another application and thus always has his cursor on a new record while actively using the database.
2. Start a timer on startup using WinAPI (could also be a hidden form with a timer instead). Use `GetLastInputInfo` to verify that the user hasn't sent any input for a set period on the timer. If it hasn't, then close down Access.

   This has the limitation that any input (e.g. a mouse that moves a tiny bit when walking past an unsteady desk) will reset the timer.

If you have trouble implementing either of these, I can provide sample code.

Comment: If you have example code for solution 2, that would be great.  I'm actually a linux guy that's dabbling with this stuff outside of my comfort zone.  My Access DB soln "stuck" and now I have to support it.  Also, it would be good to have sample code in this forum for others in the future to see too.  Thanks.

Comment: Wait, it just occurred, the users will typically have a dozen or more things running on the laptop.  If they are active doing anything at all in any window, would the timer get reset  (opt 2) ?  If so, that's not going to work.

Comment: Yup, any and all actions will reset the timer for option 2. Sounds like option 1 might be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Your better option - because of the limitations explained by Erik - would be (if not done already) to *split* the database into a frontend and a backend, *convert* the backend to SQL Server (Express edition is free to use), and *distribute* then frontend to the user's machines using a method as described in my article (if you don't have an account, browse to the link "Read the full article"):

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)

That would completely free you from the daunting tasks that keep you busy.

Comment: If every user has their own copy of the DB, how can the changes of one user be seen by the others ?

Comment: It's only the frontend to distribute. The backend is shared. If you haven't split your database, do that - there's a wizard for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that shows prmoise, from 
https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/942650-can-you-force-access-quit-when-pc-goes-into-standby-mode

Idea is to run a vbs that runs access.  If a power down event is sensed, it will disconnect the DB instead of leaving a dangling process.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objAccess, objWMIService, colItems

Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = True
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\vausamd20\SCBUDV_Infra\dbg_taskdb.accdb"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery("Select * from 
Win32_PowerManagementEvent")

Do While True
    If colItems.NextEvent.EventType = 4 Then
        objAccess.Quit
        Set objAccess = Nothing
        Set colItems = Nothing
        Set objWMIService = Nothing
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Open to comments if anyone thinks this is a good or bad idea !

Comment: I think it's a waste of time trying to come up with band-aids. The solution to a stable environment has been written up by Gustav - distributed front ends, server backend.